# Pandas deleting rows in order

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

Given a particular df:

```
ID Text
1  abc
1  xyz
2  xyz
2  abc
3  xyz
3  abc
3  ijk
4  xyz
```

I want to apply condition where: Grouping by ID, if abc exists then delete row with xyz.  The outcome would be:

```
ID Text
1  abc
2  abc
3  abc
3  ijk
4  xyz
```

Usually I would group them by Id and apply np.where(...).  However, I don't think this approach would work for this case since it's based on rows.
Many thanks!

Comment: Are you actually using `df.groupby` or do you just want to eliminate those rows with the same ID that has both abc and xyz

Comment: @DemetriP I just want to eliminate rows with xyz if there's abc for that same ID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, you can vectorize this with a `groupby` + `transform`:

```
df[~(df.Text.eq('abc').groupby(df.ID).transform('any') & df.Text.eq('xyz'))]

   ID Text
0   1  abc
3   2  abc
5   3  abc
6   3  ijk
7   4  xyz
```

Comment: that does the job!

Comment: @TylerNG I'm happy to hear that :)

Answer (score 2):

I am using `crosstab`

```
s=pd.crosstab(df.ID,df.Text)
s.xyz=s.xyz.mask(s.abc.eq(1)&s.xyz.eq(1))
s
Out[162]:
Text  abc  ijk  xyz
ID
1       1    0  NaN
2       1    0  NaN
3       1    1  NaN
4       0    0  1.0
s.replace(0,np.nan).stack().reset_index().drop(0,1)
Out[167]: 
   ID Text
0   1  abc
1   2  abc
2   3  abc
3   3  ijk
4   4  xyz
```